# Ember multiple view in same template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Im expanding the Todo example of emberjs main site ->

```
http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/accepting-edits/
```

I try to add an extra field to the model called body, and add the same logic, double click for edit. But when I add a second view the body value attached, the double-click event stops working.

I renamed the double-click event and it's not working

http://jsbin.com/atikiv/3/

Why double click is not working anymore ? Also how I can make the 2 fields are editable on double click just one ?

thx